# How can I create a pie chart in a report combining two datasets in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, rdl

My question is exactly the one I used for title. I've got an .rdl file with two datasets that are really hard to combine in one script, so I want to create a pie chart using both of them as individual datasets. I need to find the percentages of an addition of two things (one from the first dataset and one from the second), so basically i need this addition and then a division like the next one:

(first_thing+second_thing)/(sum(first_thing)+sum(second_thing))

for example I have dog_sales in the one table and cat_sales on the other and I need to do a pie chart with the percentages of the sales of both dogs and cats for this month.

How can I do it?

Comment: Are you really using SSRS 2008? If you were using SSRS 2008R2 or more recent, you could use the `LOOKUP` function in SSRS.

Comment: yeah its the r2 sorry for the wrong choice of tag

Comment: Ho do you connect the two things: do they have the same name? Can you post some sample datasets?

Comment: edited a simple example, they dont have the same name

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to join two datasets together in one pie chart.  Instead I would recommend joining your datasets into one new dataset that can be used by the pie chart.

Using your example of cat vs dog sales by month I have created an example of how to join 2 datasets together.

You can use the "total_sales" column in the final query to populate your pie chart values and you can use "month_of_sale" as the series group.

```
-- Create temp table to store Cat sales data
DECLARE @catSales TABLE(
        Sales INT
        , MonthOfSale INT);

-- Create temp table to store Dog sales data
DECLARE @dogSales TABLE(
        Sales INT
        , MonthOfSale INT)

--Populate cat sales table with data
INSERT INTO @catSales
        ( Sales, MonthOfSale )
VALUES  ( 50, -- Sales - int
          1  -- MonthOfSale - int
          )
INSERT INTO @catSales
        ( Sales, MonthOfSale )
VALUES  ( 100, -- Sales - int
          2  -- MonthOfSale - int
          )
INSERT INTO @catSales
        ( Sales, MonthOfSale )
VALUES  ( 75, -- Sales - int
          3  -- MonthOfSale - int
          )

--Populate dog sales table with data
INSERT INTO @dogSales
        ( Sales, MonthOfSale )
VALUES  ( 150, -- Sales - int
          1  -- MonthOfSale - int
          )
INSERT INTO @dogSales
        ( Sales, MonthOfSale )
VALUES  ( 80, -- Sales - int
          3  -- MonthOfSale - int
          )
INSERT INTO @dogSales
        ( Sales, MonthOfSale )
VALUES  ( 200, -- Sales - int
          4  -- MonthOfSale - int
          )

--View data in cat sales table (note that months 1, 2, and 3 are all populated with data, but not month 4.
SELECT Sales
    , MonthOfSale
FROM @catSales


--View data in dog sales table (note that months 1, 3, and 4 are all populated with data, but not month 2.
SELECT Sales
    , MonthOfSale
FROM @dogSales


--Join the data from Cat and Dog sales together based on the month
SELECT cs.sales AS 'cat_sales'
    , ds.sales AS 'dog_sales'
    , ISNULL(cs.sales, 0) + ISNULL(ds.sales, 0) AS 'total_sales' -- Use ISNULL to convert missing data into 0 so that it adds correctly
    , ISNULL(cs.MonthOfSale, ds.MonthOfSale) AS 'month_of_sale' -- If there are not cat sales, then the cs.MonthOfSale will be null and ds.MonthOfSale should be used instead
FROM @catSales cs
    FULL OUTER JOIN @dogSales ds ON cs.MonthOfSale = ds.MonthOfSale --   Use full outer join to include all data from both tables
```